# Possible to load old software raid array on new system? Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid, raid-5

I am looking into a more redundant solution to my home server.

I know raid is "not" a backup, but I am looking into a raid 5 solution for these reasons.

1. I would be very annoyed if I lost my data, but it wouldn't be the end of the world
2. I like the space efficiency of raid 5

I have ubuntu 11.04 installed on a single hard drive and don't much care about my setup and config (easy to reinstall).

If I setup a raid 5 array with the disk utility, and then my system crashes, or I have to reinstall, can I reload my raid 5 array on a new system? (fresh install)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you move all the disks that are part of a Linux software RAID5 volume (or any other RAID type) to a different computer you should be able to access the RAID volume.  I have moved sets of disks a few times.